# IntelliJ mxml giving error about id attribute used as id in typed class

Tags: actionscript, intellij-idea, mxml

I have a typed class in actionscript:

```
public class Cat {
    public var id:int;
    public var name:String;
}
```

I am using an instance variable in an mxml component:

```
<valueobjects:Cat id="selected_cat"/>
```

In IntelliJ the id for cat is coming up as an error, "invalid integer value", although it will compile without error.  This error appears in the IDE when editing the file and lists it as an error at bottom.  Does anyone know of any tricks to tell IntelliJ about this class or the property.  Or are there any metadata tags to identify the attribute so the mxml parser will be happy?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem is, that usually id is a String used in markup to set an id of type String. Flex supports that via UIComponent or IMXMLObject. You should not use ValueObjects in the markup, unless the class implements IMXMLObject.

Answer (score 0):

To declare a non-visual object in markup you have to use the fx:declarations tag in Flex 4 and above.

The id property in each mxml tag (whether visual or not) acts as a way to reference this object from the rest of the code.

In other words, its the markup equivalent of this.

var selected_car:Car

So the id has to be a String property always.

In your class you declare the id as an int property which is confusing for the compiler because it doesn't know which one is valid.

If you need to work with your class without changing it, you'll have to create instances using AS and not MXML. If you need to work with mxml (to have binding enabled etc) you'll need to change the property name to something like catID perhaps.